# how can I delete the row from datatable in UI,though i could successfully delete from server using Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a data table and in each row I have a button Delete.
ON click of Delete i am making an ajax call and deleting the row from server by passing the id.

But on success of ajax call the row is not getting deleted in the table from UI.

Below si the code.

I have rendered the column for Delete

```
{
                 "data": "Action","orderable": false, "render": function(data, type, row) {
                     userSignum=readCookie("userSignum");
                    var userIDMGroups=readCookie("nfvDBGroups");
                    var userIDMGroupsArray=userIDMGroups.split(';')
                    if((jQuery.inArray(userIDMGroups,userIDMGroupsArray ) !== -1)&&(row['signumId'] == userSignum) )
                    {
                        return '<button  class="btn btn-action deleterecord" id="'+row.id+'">Delete</button>'
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return '<button  class="btn btn-action deleterecord" id="'+row.id+'" disabled="disabled">Delete</button>'}
                    }          

             }
```

Below si the ajax call

```
 $("#searchTable tbody").on("click", ".deleterecord", function () {
         var table = $('#searchTable').DataTable();    
        var recordId=$(this).attr("id");  
          // var $row = $(this);
           if(recordId!=null){
               $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: config.vnfURL + 'vnf/delete',
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                 
                    data : JSON.stringify({"id" : recordId }),
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        // table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).remove().draw();
                        //$(recordId).remove(); 
                        table.row($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw(false);
                         alert("record deleted");
                         if(jqXHR.status == "200"){
                             className = "alert-success";
                             msg = "Record has been deleted Successfully.";
                      } else {
                             className = "alert-danger";
                             msg = "Something wrong, please try again after sometime.";
                      }
                      $("#infoDiv").addClass(className).show();
                      $("#infoDiv>center>p").html(msg);
                      setTimeout(function() { 
                             $("#infoDiv").removeClass(className).hide();
                             $("#infoDiv>center>p").html("");
                            // window.location = "/resources/search.html";
                      }, 7000); 
                    },
```

please help

Comment: get refreshed data from database and again bind with updated data

Comment: I do not want to make one more round trip to DB ,is there any other way

Comment: table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).remove().draw(); add this line on success call back of ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `this` within AJAX success callback refers to XHR object, so you may assign `const tr = table.row($(this).closest('tr'))` outside of success callback and then do `tr.remove().draw()` upon successful deletion server-side.

*p.s.* also, note that I have used [`closest('tr')`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/#closest-selector) rather than `parents('tr')` as it is less error prone, since the latter may return array if your button happen to have multiple `<tr>` parents

Answer (score 0):

Add this line on success call back of ajax

```
table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).remove().draw();
```