# Datatables row is not deleted inside $.post method

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have this block of code that works properly to delete a row from the table when I click the selected `<td>`

```
var table = $('#students-table').DataTable();
$('#students-table tbody').on('click', 'i.icon-delete', function () {
    table.row($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw();
});
```

but when I embed this line into $.post.done it doesn't work at all:

```
var table = $('#students-table').DataTable();
$('#students-table tbody').on('click', 'i.icon-delete', function () {
    var student_id = $(this).attr('student_id');
    $.post("backend.php", {"action": "deleteStudent", "student_id": student_id}).done(function (response) {
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        if (response.deleted == "1") {
            console.log("A");
            table.row($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw();
            console.log("B");
        }
    }); // post
});
```

however the condition `response.deleted == "1"` evaluates to `True` and `console.log("A");` and `console.log("B");` also works properly.
So why the row deletion line doesn't work when it's inside the `done()` function of the `$.post`

Please note that the question is not about the deletion process.

Comment: Any errors appearing in your Developer Console?

Comment: @esqew No there are no errors and the table also is constructed properly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I delete the row from datatable in UI,though i could successfully delete from server using Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56015901/how-can-i-delete-the-row-from-datatable-in-ui-though-i-could-successfully-delete)

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg No, not a duplicate. My question is all about `$(this)` not about the deletion process itself

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: @EmadSaeed : you're both doing the **same** job (deleting the rows from both front end and back end); you're both having the **same** root cause of the issue (missinterpeting `this` inside AJAX success callback) and the **same** solution will work for both of you equally - assign what's referring the table rows with `this` to the variable outside the scope of AJAX-call and use it within success callback. So, yes, it **IS** a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the callback `this` refers to the `jqXHR` object of the ajax call and not the element the event handler is bound to. So the `table.row($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw();`
 doesn't work.
More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: That's correct. Could you post a solution to complete your answer?

Answer (score 0):

As per the previews answer: `this` inside '.done()' refers to `jqXHR` not the selected element of the selector `i.icon-delete`. 
The solution is to assign the selected element `i.icon-delete` that was select by `$(this)` to a variable outside the `$.post` then use it inside `$.post` again. This way using `$(this)` would refer to `i.icon-delete` not to `jqXHR`

```
$('#students-table tbody').on('click', 'i.icon-delete', function () {
    var rowToRemove = $(this).parents('tr');
    var student_id = $(this).attr('student_id');
    $.post("backend.php", {"action": "deleteStudent", "student_id": student_id}).done(function (response) {
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        if (response.deleted == "1") {
            table.row(rowToRemove).remove().draw();
        }
    }); // post
});
```